# Base for the Topology Generated by a Family of Semi-norms?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathscr{P}$ be a family of semi-norms on a $\mathbb K=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ vector space. Can anyone help me showing the collection $$\mathscr{B}:=\left\{\bigcap_{j=1}^n B_{p_j}(x, \varepsilon_j): n\in\mathbb N, p_j\in \mathscr{P}, \varepsilon_j>0, x\in X\right\},$$ is a basis for a topology on $X$?

I'm trying to use the following result:

**Proposition:** Let $X$ be a non-empty set and $\mathscr{B}$ a family of subsets of $X$. Then $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for a topology on $X$ if and only if:

$(i)$ $\mathscr{B}$ covers $X$.

$(ii)$ If $B_1, B_2\in \mathscr{B}$ and $x\in B_1\cap B_2$ there exists $B_3\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B_3\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$.

How to show the family $\mathscr{B}$ satisfies $(ii)$?

Thanks.

**Remark:** The topology having $\mathscr{B}$ as basis is nothing but the initial topology on $X$ associated to the family of maps $\mathscr{P}$, that is, the coarsest topology on $X$ which makes each $p\in \mathscr{P}$ continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a bit of trouble thinking of a good way to write this down. The idea behind all of this is not complicated, however complicated it may seem because of my notational difficulties.

Let $B_1 = \bigcap_{i\in I} B_{p_i}(x_1, \varepsilon_i), \quad B_2 = \bigcap_{j\in J} B_{p_j}(x_2, \varepsilon_j)$, where $I$ and $J$ are of course finite. Let $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$. Let $$ \epsilon_1 := \inf_{i\in I}(\epsilon_{i} - p_i(x_1 - x))$$ and let $p_k$ ($k \in I$) be the seminorm such that this infimum is attained. Define $\epsilon_2$ and $p_{l}$ for the Set $J$ and $x_2$ analogously. Then $$ B_{p_k}(x,\epsilon_1) \cap B_{p_l}(x,\epsilon_2) \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2 $$ by the triangle inequality: Let $y \in B_{p_k}(x,\epsilon_1)$, then for all $i \in I$ $$p_i (x_1 - y) \leq p_i (x_1 - x) + p_i (x - y) \leq p_i (x_1 - x) + \epsilon_i - p_i (x_1 - x) = \epsilon_i$$ So $y \in B_1$. The rest is completely analogous.

Comment: Nice solution man, thanks =)